# 平均2乗誤差(MSE)と過学習

Tags: python

平均2乗誤差(MSE)の値を見て過学習しているかはどう判断できるのでしょうか

Answer (score 0):

訓練データのものとテストデータ（バリデーションデータ）のものとの差を確認（可視化）することで過学習の状態かどうかを判断することが出来るかと思います。
訓練データの誤差は下がり続けていくのに対し、テストデータの誤差は下がらない（上がっていく）場合に過学習を疑います。

Answer (score 0):

過学習に対して厳密な定義がないので自動判定などはある程度経験則などを組み込むことになるかと思います。
過学習と一般に言われているものはコメントでもある通り訓練データに対してのエラーが小さくなっていくのに対し、テストではいい成績が出ないような場合に過学習かな～と判断します。
過学習とは、人に例えるなら過去問は100点とれるけど本番だと40点くらいしか取れないような状態だと思います。
以上、ご参考までに。